# An unexpected error occured using ssh psql command

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssh, psql

when I run bash file in docker, I plan to run some psql command through one server A to another server (database server) that has postgresql database, but it says

```
[ERROR] [   trapError] An unexpected error occured at line 141 ./functions.sh`
```

The detail of this bash file is:

```sh
executeSql() {
  local tmp="/tmp/executeSql"
  ssh ${DBUSERHOST} "sudo -u postgres psql -c \"${SQL}\" -d studenta" > ${tmp} 2>&1
  ST=$?
  if [ "${ST}" != "0" ]; then
    ERROR "Failed to execute sql query"
    cat "${tmp}" >> "${LOGFILE}"
    exit 10
  fi
}
```

Line 141 corresponds to

```sh
ssh ${DBUSERHOST} "sudo -u postgres psql -c \"${SQL}\" -d studenta" > ${tmp} 2>&1
```

When I check the log in the PostgreSQL container, it shows this:

```
...
REVOKE
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT

LOG:  received fast shutdown request
LOG:  aborting any active transactions
FATAL:  terminating autovacuum process due to administrator command
FATAL:  terminating autovacuum process due to administrator command
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
FATAL:  terminating autovacuum process due to administrator command
waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-04-16 19:23:04 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  server process (PID 165) exited with exit code 255
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-04-16 19:28:25 UTC
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  record with zero length at 1/A5D88410
LOG:  redo is not required
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  server process (PID 200) exited with exit code 255
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-04-16 19:28:51 UTC
FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

So I guess in container A, the process stopped during running the `psql` command, which has caused database server shut down unexpectedly, I suspect it's some timeout connection, but not sure...
There is a fast shutdown in the log and when I run the bash, it exited with error immediately, as discussed in this [page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14199/postgresql-performed-a-fast-shutdown-by-itself-why-how-was-it-able-to-do-tha), it could be some unattended security updates enabled in PostgreSQL, still checking the reason...

Also, the problem is it shows only a `trapError` without further detail, so it's hard to find out the reason, can I ask if there is any solution or any way to debug into this problem?

Comment: can you share how you are bringing up the container?

Comment: I think you can add "echo ${SQL}" before execution to check if you have any additional quotas in this string.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: The interesting parts are the ones you left out: The PostgreSQL log lines immediately before what you show, where the crash should be reported, and the SQL statement you are executing and that presumably caused the problem (if it is repeatable).

Comment: It would be great to add timestamps to your log lines in PostgreSQL.  And also set `log_min_messages =  debug5` in postgresql.conf to get more debugging info in the log.  (You wouldn't want to run in production this way, but if the system isn't working then you aren't in production)